# Files.createSymbolicLink() (java.nio.file) doesn't override existing symbol link and doesn't throw exception

Tags: java

Based on the Java Doc,  it will throw FileAlreadyExistsException if the link already exists. But in the actual testing, when running follow two lines, both of them return "/tmp/ln1" and no exception is thrown. And the "ln1" is still point to "/tmp/dir1". Seems this behavior doesn't follow the documentation. It's a JDK bug?
Is there a way to override the old link? like what's the command line does: 
ln -nfs from to

```
Files.createSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/tmp/ln1"), Paths.get("/tmp/dir1"))

Files.createSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/tmp/ln1"), Paths.get("/tmp/dir2"))
```

Comment: Throws a `FileAlreadyExistsException` for me.

Comment: Yeah, you override the old link by deleting it first. --- Also, what platform (OS) are you on, and which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 4):

I use JDK 1.7. The OS is Linux. I try those two statements, it creates a symbolic link according to the first statement, and then throws a FileAlreadyExistsException for executing the second one.

If you want to override the old link, you should delete the old link before you create a new link, like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String link = "/tmp/ln1";
        // create first symbolic link
        deleteIfExists(link);
        Files.createSymbolicLink(Paths.get(link), Paths.get("/tmp/dir1"));
        //create second symbolic link
        deleteIfExists(link);
        Files.createSymbolicLink(Paths.get(link), Paths.get("/tmp/dir2"));
    }

    private static void deleteIfExists(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```